# App Inventor 2 Socket Connection (Telnet) Port 10002

Tags: android, sockets, telnet, app-inventor

I need to connect to a Telnet server with App Inventor 2.
Can this type of connection be done in **App Inventor 2**?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately not
star [issue 385](https://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=385) and/or [issue 727](https://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=727) to get an email in case there are news